# SSRS user access to specific folders

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'd appreciate if anyone could provide a clear description on SSRS user access configuration.

I've installed latest SSRS and its database on a single server, set the web portal and everything works fine, except I cannot grant access to a specific user group for a specific folder. Till now all the users have access to everything.

I've been struggling with this for several weeks and still couldn't find any tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/roles-and-permissions-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2014) Reporting Services provides an authentication subsystem and role-based authorization model. Authentication and authorization models vary depending on whether the report server runs in native mode or SharePoint mode. Here is detailed explanation called [Secure Reports and Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/secure-reports-and-resources?view=sql-server-2014) related to native mode and this one talks about [Set Permissions for Report Server Operations in a SharePoint Web Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/set-permissions-for-report-server-operations-in-a-sharepoint-web-application?view=sql-server-2014). Also this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5GZul2kJ7g) and this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSYHqkhhdOo&list=PLU7xosYbR0ASxaSQ1UyyvUAlYAz8e-FnY) was helpful to get me started.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably added the user group to a role using the **Site Settings / Security** page, or added them to the **Home folder / Manage / Security page**.  A typical user group should not appear in either list.

Instead, navigate to the **"specific folder" / Manage / Security** page, click **Customize security** (if required) and then assign the user group to a role (typically **Browser**).

Here's the full doco on those tasks:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/grant-user-access-to-a-report-server?view=sql-server-2017